# How to destroy a ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Is there any built in method available to destroy the ui-grid (angularjs) and reload it again. When i reload the grid data using ajax call it is reloading the new data, but it is not resetting the current page number (`paginationCurrentPage`) and `paginationPageSizes`

Answer (score 2):

You can use uiGridPaginationService to reset the current page and page size. The documentation is

> uiGridPaginationService(grid, currentPage, pageSize)
>
> Raises paginationChanged and calls refresh for client side pagination
>
> Parameters grid – {Grid} – the grid for which the pagination changed
>   currentPage – {int} – requested page number pageSize – {int} –
>   requested page size

Answer (score 0):

Can't you reset the page in your code?  Perhaps in the success function of your ajax call.

Comment: By "page" I meant the page number.